# WPF enable combobox based on another combobox

Tags: wpf, .net-4.5, wpf-style

I know there are already a lot of examples for doing similar things, and I have read these but cannot figure out why my implementation is not working.

I am trying to disable ComboBoxB when ComboBoxA is set to value X. With this implementation, ComboBoxB is always enabled regardless of the value selected in ComboBoxA.

ComboBoxA:

```
<ComboBox  Name="ComboBoxA">
    <ComboBoxItem Name="X">X</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Y">Y</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

ComboBoxB:

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBoxB">
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Something">Something</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,ElementName=ComboBoxA}" Value="X">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You never performed a databinding to ComboboxA.

Your referencing elementname "ComboboxA" and NOT "ComboboxB"

You have:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,ElementName=ComboBoxB}" Value="X">
```

This should be:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,ElementName=ComboBoxA}" Value="X">
```

.

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBoxB">
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Something">Something</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,ElementName=ComboBoxA}" Value="X">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo when I simplified the names used in the question. My real ComboBoxB is bound correctly to ComboBoxA. (I updated the example) but this is not working for me. Any ideas?

Comment: In your output window, do you observe any binding errors?

Comment: No errors in the output, or error list. I can update the question with my actual code if there are no errors visible in the simple example I posted.

Comment: If you're keep track of the value in the CBItem by name you might want to consider moving that value over to the tag property. It's a free tag you can assign a value to and reference or bind too when needed. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could use converters to do this.

```
public class SelectedItemToDisable : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

         if (value != null)
         {
            var val = (value as ComboBoxItem).Content;
             if (val.ToString() == "X") //may be its not string, some object type 
                 return false;
         }
        return true;
    }
```

define the converter in resources part in Xaml.

```
<local:SelectedItemToDisable x:Key="DisableConverter"/>

<ComboBox  Name="ComboBoxA">
 <ComboBoxItem Name="X">X</ComboBoxItem>
 <ComboBoxItem Name="Y">Y</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
<ComboBox Name="ComboBoxB" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=ComboBoxA, Converter={StaticResource DisableConverter}}">
 <ComboBoxItem Name="Something">Something</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Hope this helps.